# recyclerView scrollListener is calling triggering with oncreateView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

when fragment is rendering first time its calling scroll listener of recyclerview causing bugs, here is my code

```
 viewPagerDetail.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {


            int tab= linearVertical.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (tab>=0 && tab < tabLayoutDetail.getTabCount()) {
                tabLayoutDetail.getTabAt(tab).select();
            }

            viewPagerDetail.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Comment: are you using custom adapter?

Comment: I'm attaching tablayout with recyclerview to add navigation dots to recyclerview, followed this:   https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/advanced-recyclerview

Comment: using this, by default tab selected at 3 or 4 position, first tabs are added then tab selected listener called and then recyclerview on scroll called

Comment: This might not help at all, but if you are making your own adapter extending RecyclerView.Adapter , you should use this: ((NameOfYourAdapter) viewPagerDetail.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: ((NameOfYourAdapter) viewPagerDetail.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); for?

Comment: last line, updating your RecyclerView

Comment: I used it to bind some value, not for scrolling to position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170951/discussion-between-blackhawk-and-theengineer).